# Erro ao tentar consultar via HQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

Eu tenho as seguintes entidades:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name="objeto")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Objeto implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 13, unique = true)
    private String numero;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String sigla;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String nome;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String categoria;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement(name = "evento")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "objeto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Evento> eventos;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String erro;

}
```

Evento:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name = "evento")
public class Evento implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String tipo;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private Integer status;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlTransient
    @Column
    private LocalDate data;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement(name = "data")
    @Transient
    private String dataAux;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlTransient
    @Column
    private LocalTime hora;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement(name = "hora")
    @Transient
    private String horaAux;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String descricao;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String recebedor;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String documento;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String comentario;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String local;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private Integer codigo;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String cidade;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String uf;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "evento", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Destino destino;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "objeto_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Objeto objeto;

}
```

Destino:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name = "destino")
public class Destino implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String local;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private Integer codigo;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String cidade;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String uf;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "evento_id")
    private Evento evento;

}
```

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta onde quero retornar um `List` de `Objeto` desde que nos seus eventos não contenha um evento cuja descrição é *Objeto entregue ao destinatário*. Minha consulta ficou assim:

```
public List<Objeto> obterObjetosPendentes() {
        List<Objeto> retorno = new ArrayList<Objeto>();
        final StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder();
        hql.append("select objeto from Objeto objeto ");
        hql.append("inner join Evento evento where evento.descricao != :descricao");
        final Query query = this.em.createQuery(hql.toString());
        query.setParameter("descricao", "Objeto entregue ao destinatário");
        retorno = query.getResultList();
        return retorno;
    }
```

Mas tenho o erro na execução:

```
2018-03-15 13:39:34,256 WARNING [com.roknauta.tracker.controller.ObjetoController] (default task-54) Objeto LB624873525SE já cadastrado
2018-03-15 13:39:43,047 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-54) SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
2018-03-15 13:39:43,051 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-54) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where evento1_.descricao<>'Objeto entregue ao destinatário'' at line 1
2018-03-15 13:39:43,099 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-54) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component ObjetoService for method public java.util.List com.roknauta.tracker.service.ObjetoService.obterObjetosPendentes(): javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:188)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:332)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:240)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(
```

Onde está o erro ? Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, eu esqueci de fazer o relacionamento entre Objeto e Evento na query. Percebi isso quando liguei os logs do sql e vi o sql que foi pro banco. Sendo assim, minha consulta agora está:

```
public List<Objeto> obterObjetosPendentes() {
        List<Objeto> retorno = new ArrayList<Objeto>();
        final StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder();
        hql.append("select objeto from Objeto objeto ");
        hql.append("inner join objeto.eventos evento where evento.descricao != :descricao");
        final Query query = this.em.createQuery(hql.toString());
        query.setParameter("descricao", "Objeto entregue ao destinatário");
        retorno = query.getResultList();
        return retorno;
    }
```